# How to search and replace classes like {classname}Attribute with {classname} classes with Resharper or VS?

Tags: c#, replace, resharper

I want to use Resharper or Visual Studio to search and replace every usage of classes like XmlTypeAttribute with the shorter name for that classes: XmlType.

The search and replace should work just for the classes which inherits from System.Attribute

How can I do it?
Is it possibile to do it code using Resharper?

Comment: A simple Find and Replace should suffice.  Check the "Match Whole Word" checkbox, and Look in Entire Solution.  You shouldn't have to do this more than a few times, so it doesn't really make much sense to code up an entire solution to solve it.

Comment: There is a problem with XmlAttributeAttribute class.. I cannot replace XmlAttribute with Xml..

Comment: I could do it in 2 steps:
XmlAttribute => XmlAttributeAttribute +
(.+)Attribute => $1; but it's not very good.. I would prefer to do it using resharper and checking if the matched class name is derived by System.Attribute

Comment: Is Resharper capable of doing that?

Comment: I fear it's not.. I've open an issue on their website: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-398063 if I'm wrong and it's capable, please let me know.